# How to permute elements in a list

Tags: list-manipulation, cryptography

I am attempting to decrypt a ciphertext. I split the cipher into blocks of five, and now I want to permute each individual block. My goal is to be able to permute each individual block by the same permutation and then combine the list into one string which I will attempt to decrypt from there. I am not asking for assistance on decrypting the ciphertext, but I do need help learning how to permute this. Here is what I am currently trying, and, as you can see, I am permuting the blocks in the list rather than the elements in the blocks.

[image: What I am trying now]

Comment: Could you post it as code we can copy.

Answer (score 3):

```
stringPermute[str_?StringQ, perm_] := StringJoin@Permute[Characters@str, perm]

stringPermute["JZGRV", FindPermutation[{1, 3, 2, 4, 5}]]

perm = FindPermutation[{1, 3, 2, 4, 5}];
stringPermute[#,perm] /@ {"XYZWQ", "ABCDE", "FJRCT"}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could split the strings into lists of characters and apply the permutation (or its inverse) by just reading it off. Afterwards, you can create the strings by mapping `StringJoin`:

```
p = {1, 3, 2, 4, 5};
q = InversePermutation[p];
StringJoin /@ Characters[{"ABCDG", "EFGHI", "JKLMN"}][[All, p]]
StringJoin /@ Characters[{"ABCDG", "EFGHI", "JKLMN"}][[All, q]]
```

> {"ACBDG", "EGFHI", "JLKMN"}

> {"ACBDG", "EGFHI", "JLKMN"}

Comment: `InversePermutation[{1,3,2,4,5}]` returns `{1,3,2,4,5}` which is the same - i.e self inverse, but your outputs are the same.

Comment: Of course: `p` is an involution so it has the same effect as its inverse.

Comment: Thanks I got confused why you were showing the inverse acting on A**BC**DG, when I thought you were trying to undo the permutation on A**CB**DG.